# Add class in drop area (file input) when dragging an external image over (dragenter) in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, vue.js, fileapi

I've built a simple Drag & Drop image preview over the file input in Vue. It's works fine but when the image is dragged over the dropzone I want to add a class so it will highlight the area, which it already does when you hover over it.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <upload-image help="Specific requirements for this dropzone"></upload-image>
</div>

<template id="dropzone">
  <div v-if="!image">
      <div class="dropzone-area" drag-over="handleDragOver">
          <div class="dropzone-text">
              <span class="dropzone-title">Drop image here or click to select</span>
              <span class="dropzone-info" v-if="help">{{ help }}</span>
          </div>
          <input type="file" @change="onFileChange">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropzone-preview">
      <img :src="image" />
      <button @click="removeImage" v-if="image">Remove</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

JavaScript (Vue.js):

```
Vue.component('upload-image', {

  template: '#dropzone',

  props: ['help'],

  data() {
      return {
          image: ''
      }
  },

  methods: {
      onFileChange(e) {
          var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
          if (!files.length) return;
          this.createImage(files[0]);
      },
      createImage(file) {
          var image = new Image();
          var reader = new FileReader();
          var vm = this;

          reader.onload = (e) => {
              vm.image = e.target.result;
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      },
      removeImage: function (e) {
          this.image = '';
      }
  }

});

new Vue({
    el: '#wrapper'
});
```

Here is my example fiddle (with styling): https://jsfiddle.net/jackbarham/sxfept4t/1

I can get it to work (on a static HTML element) using [dragenter in vanilla JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragenter#Example), but not when the element is generated by Vue.

Comment: Where is `handleDragOver` defined?

Answer (score 6):

Use `@dragenter` attribute to bind your method to a dragenter event.

```
<div :class="['dropzone-area', dragging ? 'dragenterClass' : '']" drag-over="handleDragOver" @dragenter="dragging=true" @dragend="dragging=false" @dragleave="dragging=false">
...
</div>
```

And in a data section:

```
data() {
      return {
          image: '',
          dragging: false
      }
}
```

---

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/panamaprophet/0L2433gu/) based on your code.

Comment: `@dragover="dragging=true" @drop="dragging=false" @dragleave="dragging=false"` this works better

Answer (score -3):

Question was answered here: http://forum.vuejs.org/topic/1446/add-class-in-drop-area-file-input-when-dragging-an-external-image-over-dragenter/2

With: `@dragenter`, `@dragleave` and the `:class` binding to the rescue

Comment: Link does not exist